# Do you always have to set ViewBag variables in order to access data from the controller

Tags: c#, .net, razor, viewbag

I have a controller like this:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Index";
            ViewBag.LoggedIn = TheUser.CheckStatus();

            return View();
        }
```

Thing is, I have to set LoggedIn to the output of my other function TheUser.CheckStatus() so that I can reference it with razor... Is there a way in Razor to access a function straight off? for example...

```
@TheUser.CheckStatus
```

instead of

```
@ViewBag.LoggedIn
```

Comment: use "ViewModel" classes instead of ViewBag.

Comment: New to .NET, what are they? Can I have some syntax example :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way in MVC for passing information to a view is to create a model specific to that view (aka view model) e.g.

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
}
....
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new IndexViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Index",
        IsAuthenticated = UserIsLoggedIn()
    });
}
```

However, to answer your question:

> Is there a way in Razor to access a function straight off?

If you are using ASP.NET Membership you can use the [IsAuthenticated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated.aspx) property on the request e.g.

```
 @Request.IsAuthenticated
```

Otherwise, you do need to pass this information to the view (whether that be via `ViewBag`/view model etc.)

Alternatively, you could write your own extension method for `Request` which would allow you to access it directly in the view:

```
@Request.UserLoggedIn()
```

Or even as a `HtmlHelper` e.g.

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{ 
    public static bool UserIsLoggedIn(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        return /* authentication code here */
    }
}
```

Then in your views you can use `@Html.UserIsLoggedIn()` which I *think* is what you are after.

Answer (score 4):

use a ViewModel class (your view will then be strongly typed, and you'll be able to use "classic" helpers).

```
//viewModel class
public class UserStatusViewModel {
   public string Title {get;set;}
   public bool IsLogged {get;set;
}


//action
public ActionResult Index() {
  var model = new UserStatusViewModel{ Title = "Index", IsLogged = TheUser.CheckStatus()};
  return View(model);
}

//view

@model UserStatusViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Title)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.IsLoggedIn)
```